# jQuery tab function not switching successfully between divs

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

jQuery hates me... I've got a group of images set in a table, each with an associated form inside a div below... I want to be able to switch between these forms/divs by harnessing the images as 'tabs', yet it doesn't seem to work. All I've managed to do is get it to hide the div's which aren't the first. It's the most basic thing ever.

Here's an example of my HTML which I am trying to modify using jQuery:

```
<table id="publishimages">
  <tr>
    <td href="#tab-1">
      <img class="image1" src="randomsource1">
    </td>
    <td href="#tab-2">
      <img class="image2" src="randomsource2">
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<div id="desc">
  <div id="tab-1">
    Random description1
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2">
    Random description2
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my jQuery script...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#desc div').hide();
        $('#desc div:first').show();
        $('#desc td:first').addClass('active');

        $('#desc td img').click(function() {
            $('#desc td').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            var currentTab = $(this).parent().attr('href');
            $('#desc div').hide();
            $(currentTab).show();
            return false;

        });
    });
```

What is so terribly wrong about this? Is there a more effective way of debugging JavaScript rather than trial and error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi corrected your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#desc div').hide();              
            $('#desc div:first').show();                
            $('#publishimages td:first').addClass('active');        
            $('#publishimages td').click(function(){                    
                $('#publishimages td').removeClass('active');                   
                $(this).addClass('active');                 
                var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');                  
                $('#desc div').hide();                  
                $(currentTab).show();                   
                return false;
                });
    });
```

This will do the needful.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you so much! I am studying the differences in your code vs. mine intently! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code lacking here:

```
$('#desc td:first').addClass('active');
```

which should be:

```
$('#publishimages td:first').addClass('active');
```

and these:

```
$('#desc td img').click(function() {
        $('#desc td').removeClass('active');
```

should be:

```
$('#publishimages td img').click(function() {
        $('#publishimages td').removeClass('active');
```